# how to catch program shutdown to release resources?

Tags: c#, .net

In my program i'm using

```
logWriter = File.CreateText(logFileName);
```

to store logs.

Should I call logWriter.Close() and where? Should it be `finalizer` or something?

Comment: You should always close the handle to the file, ideally as soon as you are done writing to it, or on program exit? If you are using this to potentially log errors you should make sure that it is closed properly in the event of an error/exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should close your file when you're done with it. You can create a log class ( or use an existing one like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) ) and implement IDisposable and inside the `Dispose`-method you release the resources.

You can wrap it with a `using`-block, but I would rather have it in a seperate class. This way in the future you can handle more advance logging, for instance, what happens when your application runs on multiple threads and you try to write to the file at the same time?

log4net can be configured to use a [text-file or a database](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) and it's easy to change if the applications grows.

Answer (score 3):

The normal approach is to wrap `File.CreateText` in a `using` statement

```
using (var logWriter = File.CreateText(logFileName))
{
    //do stuff with logWriter 
}
```

However, this is inconvenient if you want `logWriter` to live for the duration of your app since you most likely won't want the `using` statement wrapping around your app's `Main` method.

In which case you must make sure that you call `Dispose` on `logWriter` before the app terminates which is exactly what `using` does for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a log file which you wish to keep open, then the OS will release the file as part of shutting the process down when the application exits. You do not actually have to manage this explicitly.

One issue with letting the OS clean up your file handle, is that your file writer will use buffering and it may need flushing before it will write out the remains of its buffer. If you do not call close\dispose on it you may lose information. One way of forcing a flush is to hook the `AppDomain` unload event which will get called when your .Net process shuts down, e.g.:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += delegate { logWriter.Dispose(); };
```

There is a time limit on what can occur in a domain unload event handler, but writing the remains of a file writer buffer out is well within this. I am assuming you have a default setup i.e. one default `AppDomain`, otherwise things get tricky all round including logging.

If you are keeping your file open, consider opening it with access rights that will allow other processes to have read access. This will enable a program such as a file tailer or text editor to be used to read the file whilst your program is running.